# Cygwin shell fatal error - prefork: couldn't create pipe process

Tags: cygwin

When I start the Cygwin shell in Windows XP, I get a stream of messages like this:

```
0 [main] -bash 2920 C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - prefork: couldn't create pipe process trackerWin32 error 161
```

I get yet more messages whenever I run scripts and commands. The shell appears to work underneath the flood of errors, but it is very annoying.

Is there any way to find out what is causing this or to fix it?

Comment: Might be a rebase problem. Running [rebaseall](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall) might fix this.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have fixed it, I still get the same errors.